Antd select component does not set actual form value when setFieldsValue
Background:
I am using antd select component in my form for tagging. This form is used to update the backend on changes on an entity. Hence on first load, I would like to update the select component to show the existing tags. To do so, I used the form.setFieldsValue method to update the form. (there are some other fields as well)
Problem
When using setFieldsValue, I inserted a LabelObject with the tags label and value. If I do not update the tags field, the form value seems to stay as the object rather than the value and will submit the form with the tags field as objects.
How do i get the tags field to update with the initial value while allowing my tags to display correctly?
Code snippets
const UpdateForm = ({ initialValues }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (initialValues) {
            let formDisplayValue = { ...initialValues }

            form.setFieldsValue({
                ...formDisplayValue,
                country: formDisplayValue.country.code,
                tags: formDisplayValue.tags?.map((val) => {
                    return { value: val.id, label: val.name, name: val.name }
                })
            });
        }
    }, [form, initialValues]);

    return (
        <Form
            form={form}
            name="basic"
            autoComplete="off"
        >
            ...
            <TagSelectComponent />
        </Form>
    )
}

const TagSelectComponent = () => {
    const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState([]);
    const [value, setValue] = useState();

    const handleSearch = async (newValue) => {
        const { data } = await searchTags(newValue);
        setSearchData((data?.tags || []).map((val) => { return { value: val.id, label: val.name } }))
    };

    const handleChange = (newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };

    return <Form.Item label="Tags" name="tags">
        <Select
            mode="multiple"
            showSearch
            value={value}
            placeholder={"tags"}
            defaultActiveFirstOption={false}
            suffixIcon={null}
            filterOption={false}
            onSearch={handleSearch}
            onChange={handleChange}
            notFoundContent={null}
            options={(searchData || []).map((d) => ({
                value: d.value,
                label: d.label,
            }))}
            labelRender={(val) => {
                return val.label
            }}
        />
    </Form.Item>
}

I kind of understand that setting the fields value using setFieldsValue is causing the form value to be set as the object passed in. but i do not know how i am able to get the tags to still display correctly (with the labels) if i just set the correct value.
Note: I do not want to add another API call just to get the tag info for update as i feel is quite wasteful.

Please can you share minimal working code URL?

Ant Design's Select component has a prop called labelInValue maybe this can help you but I am not sure until I would be able to see working example.

Did you try to use "initialValues" prop? Is a prop from  component used to set the initial value once rendered the first time. You should skip the use of useEffect to in that case and manipulate the intitialValues :
   let formValues = {}
   if (initialValues) {
        let formDisplayValue = { ...initialValues }

        formValues = {
            ...initialValues,
            country: initialValues.country.code,
            tags: initialValues.tags?.map((val) => {
                return { value: val.id, label: val.name, name: val.name }
            })
        }
    }

FORM:
<Form initialValue={formValues} ....../>

You should then use "onValuesChange" Form prop to manage values change insted of u custom handleChange for any single Form.Item component.
There's non need to do that
  options={(searchData || []).map((d) => ({
            value: d.value,
            label: d.label,
        }))}

if your searchData is already an Array of Object like {value: '', label: ''}

yes i did, using initialValue yield the same result. i think the form is setting the object as the value without any further processing. Need to find a way to process the inital value as well.

Are you sure that Antd Select can return an object (or Array of object)as value? I tried in many ways but it always return only values as Array( tag mode, multiple or single). Maybe for some reasons in the beginning before any interaction on submit, the Form component itself preserve the initial Object value (label + value).
I suggest you to create a sort of mapping of your options and on submit, create an Array of items filtered by value.

That was my workaround. i checked if it was and object. and it its an object, i would do some processing to just get the ID that i need and send it as an array. thanks!
